# Adding an image instead of text in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a filter in a wordpress plugin and when there are no more posts in this filter, its displays the following indicating that there are no more posts available

`echo '        loadMoreEndTxt:"' . esc_attr__('no more posts', ESG_TEXTDOMAIN) . '",' . "\n";`

can i change this to replace 'no more posts' with an image instead of the default text

I tried ('') but its just displaying the code, and a few other things after a few online searches but all failed

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the HTML to display the image instead of plain text:

```
echo 'loadMoreEndTxt: "<img src="' . esc_url(IMAGE_URL_HERE) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__('No more posts', ESG_TEXTDOMAIN) . '">',';
```